# Selecting Metrics in Keras CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use CNN for trying to classify cats/dogs and noticed something strange.

When i define the model compile statement as below -

```
cat_dog_model.compile(optimizer =optimizers.Adam(),
                      metrics= [metrics.Accuracy()], loss=losses.binary_crossentropy)
```

my accuracy is very bad - something like 0.15% after 25 epochs.

When i define the same as

```
cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

my accuracy shoots upto 55% in the first epoch and almost 80% by epoch 25.

When I read the Keras doc - https://keras.io/api/optimizers/ they mention explicitly that

> You can either instantiate an optimizer before passing it to `model.compile()`, as in the above example, or you can pass it by its string identifier. In the latter case, the default parameters for the optimizer will be used.

Also the metrics parameter are also as per the API - [Keras Metrics API](https://keras.io/api/metrics/accuracy_metrics/)

So as per my understanding i am using default parameters on both. Also when i change the metrics parameter to hardcode I get the same accuracy. So somehow the accuracy metrics is causing this issue. But I cant figure out why - Any help is appreciated.

My qn is why is hard coding metrics better than defining it as parameter?

Some more details : I am trying to use 8k images for training and about 2k images for validation.

sample code (you can change the line number 32 to get different results) :

```
from keras import models, layers, losses, metrics, optimizers
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img,img_to_array

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,shear_range = 0.2,zoom_range = 0.2,horizontal_flip = True)

train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/....../training_set/',
        target_size = (64, 64),batch_size = 32,class_mode = 'binary')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/drive/MyDrive/........./test_set/',
        target_size = (64, 64),batch_size = 32,class_mode = 'binary')

cat_dog_model = models.Sequential()
cat_dog_model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[64, 64, 3]))
cat_dog_model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cat_dog_model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cat_dog_model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2) )
cat_dog_model.add(layers.Flatten())
cat_dog_model.add(layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cat_dog_model.add(layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

cat_dog_model.compile(optimizer =optimizers.Adam(), metrics= [metrics.Accuracy()], loss=losses.binary_crossentropy)

cat_dog_model.summary()

cat_dog_model.fit(x=train_set,validation_data=test_set, epochs=25)
```

Comment: They should be both the same. Under the hood, keras map the string to Optimizer class and initiate it with the default parameters as you said. In order to make sure, you need to fix your random seed and try with both methods. Then you will see that you the matched results. To fix the seed, check this [link](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development)

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What is your question?

Comment: @Coderji arguably, a difference in accuracy between 15% and 80% cannot be attributed to the random seed

Comment: @desertnaut it still can happen, specially the image model is very small and have only 8K of data to train with no transfer learning. Additionally there are alot of randomness happening in the image generator that can give different results. At the end optimizer string are mapped to the correspondent object using Factory design pattern not more or less.

Comment: don't think it is the optimizer. Think it is the way you defined the metric.. Try defining the metric in the same way for both cases of optimizer.

Comment: @GerryP - thank you. It was indeed the metrics.. but why is the metrics causing so much of an issue. The api page (https://keras.io/api/metrics/accuracy_metrics/) says we can use it this way so why is it happening.. I will also modify the qn accordingly